# Is there a way to keep track of triggered cloud task queues in Google app engine, so I can find out when they are fully executed?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, task-queue, google-cloud-tasks

I have a use case which requires me to keep track if all the taskqueues triggered inside a loop are executed or not. Once ALL of the taskqueues are executed(ALL, not a few), only then I can proceed with the next phase of my task. I want to keep track of this in the code itself, not from the Cloud Tasks page in the console.

In this code, I am triggering the taskqueues in this way:-

```
for item in listA:
  execute taskqueue1


inside taskqueue1 function:-

for b in listB:
 execute taskqueue2
```

I need to find out if all the taskqueues in loops of listA and listB are completed. Is there a way to keep track of the statuses of all the triggered taskqueues?

All taskqueues are push queues.

Answer (score 0):

While reviewing Python documentation,I found a link that could help you with your case:
https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

In this article, you can find the next topics:

- What is a Thread ?
- How to create threads and wait for them to finish
- How to use a ThreadPoolExecutor
- How to avoid race conditions
- How to use the common tools that Python threading provides

If you are not sure whether you want to use `Python threading, asyncio or multiprocessing`, then you can check out Speed up your Python Program with Concurrency:

https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/

Here is also a Python Github repo tutorial that could be helpful:       https://github.com/realpython/materials/tree/master/intro-to-threading

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but this won't work on cloud taskqueues